# VBA loop to paste value in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I hope one of you could help me resolving this issue:

In Sheet1, I have a combobox with names from "Sem1" to "Sem52". These names also correspond to sheet names (so "Sem1", "Sem2",...). According to the text selected in the combobox, I would like to paste value from Sheet1 to the related sheet.
I let you hereunder my drafted code and the idea would be to avoid repeating my IF conditions 52 times ! I guess I need to set up a new variable (e.g. Dim i as integer, for i = 1 to 52) but I don't really know how to make it.

Thanks for your help

```
Dim cmbx As ComboBox
Set cmbx = Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1

If cmbx.Text = "Sem1" Then

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("c41:c42").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sem1").Select
    Range("p34").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drive the sheet you are working with based on the selected text:

```
Dim cmbx As ComboBox
Set cmbx = Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c41:c42").Copy
Sheets(cmbx.Text).Range("p34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Since the options available in your combobox all match the names of the respective sheet, the appropriate sheet is selected (which matches the name of the user selection) and then manipulated.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the idea but it doesn't really work. The two tricky parts of the code that need to be adjusted are (i) If cmbx.Text = "Sem1" Then and (ii) Sheets("Sem1").Select. The selection in the combobx has to trigger the selection of the related sheet in which i can paste some data. thanks again for your advice

Comment: @Dugaet - No problem then - it is actually much easier to do this. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 6
    If cmbx.Text = ("Sem" && i) Then
       ...
Next i
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help but the following code doesn't work             If cmbx.Text = ("Sem" && i) Then

Answer (score 0):

You can **PasteSpecial** in many sheets **without** a loop.  Here is an example for **2** destinations:

```
Sub dural()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C40:C41").Copy
    Sheets(Array("Sem1", "Sem2")).Select
    Range("P34").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is that I only want to copy values in the sheet selected by the user. If he selects Sem1, then the value will be copied in the sheet Sem1.